# Fixed Array?/ StringBuilder?/ String? which is best way to create a string, if 84 strings to be appended

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder

I know in advance that, there would be 84 strings going to be appended by comma  separator, to create one string then,

Which way is be better a fixed Array, Strings or String Builder?

Comment: Are these 84 string dynamic i.e generated at runtime? or u know all the string at compile time?

Comment: That hugely depends on your use-case and can not be answered without a clear definition of such use-case. Also what is "better"? Better in what sense? There are hundreds of metrics you could apply. Speed? Memory usage? Readability?

Comment: Yes the values of 84 strings would be dynamic

Comment: Probably [`String.join(", ", list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) but it depends somewhat on your use case.

Comment: And usse case is I could have 100 records and for each record I need to  generate 84 length string which would be formed from this 84 strings, and at the end all 84 length strings needs to be appended to form a big String

Comment: @Ben I'm curious to hear the other 97. ;)

Comment: @Michael Let's call it an euphemistic exaggeration ;)

Comment: @Michael `String.join("," + " ", list)`, `String.join(new String(",") + " ", list)`, ... ;)

Comment: @daniu no, no. Hundred of metrics, not hundreds of solutions!

Comment: Having looked at the implementation of `String.join` (in JDK8)...wow would it not fit the definition of "best" if "best" is interpreted as "most runtime or memory efficient." Yikes.

Comment: I would say better in all the terms Speed, Memory usage, Readability. What would be the better option, I though of String then I realized that it would generate many string being immutable nature

Comment: @Michael oh... and I was so glad I got to contribute

Comment: @daniu Well don't let me stop you if you wanna come up with the rest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "best" you mean "most memory and/or runtime efficient" then you're probably best off with a `StringBuilder` you pre-allocate. (Having looked at the implementation of `String.join` in the JDK, it uses `StringJoiner`, which uses a `StringBuilder` with the default initial capacity [16 chars] with no attempt to avoid reallocation and copying.)

You'd sum up the lengths of your 84 strings, add in the number of commas, create a `StringBuilder` with that length, add them all, and call `toString` on it. E.g.:

```
int length = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; ++i) {
    length += strings[i].length();
}
length += strings.length - 1; // For the commas
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
sb.append(strings[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < strings.length; ++i) {
    sb.append(',');
    sb.append(strings[i]);
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Ah I see. I thought it was going to be something really bad, like it was just concatenating `String` objects together.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder very well explained. the question about why to use stringBuilder

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways of doing that.

My preferred way of doing it (which may or may not be the best) would be to convert my 84 strings into a stream (with `Arrays.stream()` or `list.stream()`, depending how the strings are actually stored) and then do [`Collectors.joining(",")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-).

That is, if you already have an array, `String.join(",", array)` will do the trick as well, as noted in another answer.

Comment: Internally `Collectors.joining` uses a [`StringJoiner'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html). But I would write it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) to build the String. It would be like using `StringBuilder`, but you don't need to worry about the commas (and you can even append and prepend a value if you want).

This is mainly useful when you're building the result in parts, or when you may omit some elements. Otherwise it offers no benefits vs. `Collectors.joining()` or `String.join()` (which internally uses `StringJoiner` anyway).