# Using a StringBuilder, can we convert it to String with semicolon as a string separator?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

If I use an `StringBuilder`, can we covert it to a `String` with semicolon as a string separator?

So I have StringBuilder object like,

```
SomeRecord s = SomeRecord.builder()
        .field1("A")
        .field2("B")
        .field3("C")
        .build();
```

I need to covert it to string but new String should be separated with ";"

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output?  What is the logic behind where a semicolon separator gets applied to the string/string builder?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but if you wish to join strings with a delimiter you should use the StringJoiner class.

Comment: I will update the question

Comment: You should've continued on your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326014/fixed-array-stringbuilder-string-which-is-best-way-to-create-a-string-if-8) about this.

Comment: Based on your edit just now all I can say is, you have an object of type `SomeRecord` and not `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Kayaman, the previous question was already had lots of comments so I have created a new one after reading some stuff related to it

Comment: @Ben, sorry you are right its a wrong question, I will delete it,

Comment: Again: you ask about **StringBUilder**, but in your example, you are not using that class. You are using a **SomeRecord BUILDER**. Which we know nothing about

Comment: Its a wrong question I agree, please do not answer, I cant delete it. I'm sorry and thank  you for your replies

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather roundabout way to add semicolons between your strings. Instead, consider adding a `.append(";")` call after every other append call, or using a `StringJoiner`, as Jotunacorn suggests.

Also, to convert a `StringBuilder` to a `String`, call `.toString()` after all desired text is appended.

Comment: This makes the most sense to me, adding separators as the StringBuilder is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you append the `StringBuilder`, you could use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) instead of a `StringBuilder`.

```
String[] datas = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
String s = String.join(";", datas);
```

> a;b;c

Or with a define number of values, you can call the method directly since this accept a varargs parameter `CharSequence...` :

```
String s = String.join(";", getFieldA(), getFieldB(), getFieldC());
```